# AltGr not working on system but correct output in xev (18.04)

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, keyboard-layout, xev

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and I'm using an Italian keyboard layout. Until 17.10, I had to manually set up the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key with the `xmodmap` command with the following command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Mode_switch"
```

After this, the key would work correctly and allow me to type characters that aren't present on the keyboard.

Since the update however I am unable to make it work. I tried setting up the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key to be either `Mode_switch` or `ISO_Level3_Shift`, but neither of those seem to work. `Mode_switch` does nothing, and with `ISO_Level3_Shift` either I don't get any output, I get the same key without the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key, or I get gibberish.

However, once I try to use the `xev` command to check for problems, the output seem to be correct. For example, the following is the result of me trying to type <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>ò</kbd> on my keyboard, which is the combination to get the `#` character:

```
# press AltGr
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x5c9, subw 0x0, time 910833, (94,262), root:(965,712),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

# press ò
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x5c9, subw 0x0, time 911417, (94,262), root:(965,712),
    state 0x98, keycode 48 (keysym 0x23, numbersign), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (23) "#"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (23) "#"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

# release ò
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x5c9, subw 0x0, time 911737, (94,262), root:(965,712),
    state 0x98, keycode 48 (keysym 0x23, numbersign), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (23) "#"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

# release AltGr
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x5c9, subw 0x0, time 912169, (94,262), root:(965,712),
    state 0x98, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

It looks like it interprets the `#` character correctly, so it seems to be a communication problem inside X-org itself, but I'm at a loss as to why or how.

I know it is an X.org problem and not a keyboard one because I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> at any time and use the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> correctly in the terminal (besides the fact that it worked fine until I upgraded)

Does anyone have a clue what may be happening here?

**EDIT:** I got my hands on another keyboard and on this one <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> works without problems under xfce. And this one also gives this `XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92` line, so it doesn't seem to be the culprit.

At this point I'm guessing there is something strange happening in the communication of the keyboard that throws X.org a little off. I'm not sure if there is an actual solution. If anyone has any ideas I will test them, since I don't want to put a keyboard to waste, but for now I will just use the new keyboard.

Comment: `XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92` could be the problem. Modifying the keysym mapping rarely results in the desired behaviour. Did the keyboard ever work as expected (without modification of the keysym mapping)?

Comment: @danzel It works fine in TTY1 and in xubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0):

So I found a "solution". I just disconnected and reconnected the keyboard, and now it works just fine. However this has to be done everytime I log out (but it is not affected by standby). While not a perfect solution at least now I can use it.

Feels like a bug in X.org, which I will report.

I will not accept this answer in case anyone has some other opinion on what may be going on.